# CSS - Twitter Bootstrap: Centering Thumbnail grid and removing border from links/images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to create an image grid. This is the **HTML** Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span6">
        <a href="x" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.loremipsum.com" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.contaner -->
```

**The problem:**

That grid is not centered on the page, the left margin is always smaller than the right margin.

I already tried to set `text-align: center` to the parent elements: No luck.

I also tried

```
.thumbnails { text-align:center; }
.thumbnails > li > a { display: inline-block; float: none; }
```

Guess what? No luck!

Working with offsets also has no effects.

*What can I do to center this grid?* If needed I can supply screenshots.

*Also, is there a way to remove the border from the links?* I already commented out in `thumbnails.less`, but that gave me some compiler errors somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick jsfiddle ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/4NQTp/4/)) where I used background colors on the .row and .container to show what's happening. I used two span6's with your code structure, if you only need one span6, just remove the other. As for the border, you have to adjust both the box-shadow and the border on the .thumbnail class, since the box-shadow plays a part in the appearance of the border.

Here is another jsfiddle ([2nd jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/ufyjf/6/)) that does not use `ul`s/`li`s, but does use `.row-fluid` and puts the `.thumbnails` class inside the grid. In this version the thumbnails are centered in the span6's.

This last example ([3rd jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonschlinkert/ufyjf/14/)) uses `.row-fluid` and a custom class, `.thumbnail-container` to wrap the thumbnails and center them inside the grid. If you nest a `.row-fluid` inside a regular `.row` remember that you need to use a `.span12` for the fluid row to span the entire width of whatever container it's in. This is because fluid rows use percentages.

Hopefully one of these examples leads you to an answer. I can help you get this working exactly how you want, but I would need to know more specifics. If the fiddles I did don't help you, please let me know what's not working with more details and I'll try to get you the rest of the way. In particular, how many thumbs are on each row and what size (it's not pertinent, but helps with the example), and are you using two span6's? basically two columns? or are you only using the one span6 for your images? Stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried all your examples, but none of them lead me to the desired results, so here are more infos. I am using the code inside a Wordpress template. I actually don't know the dimensions of the images. Some of them are portrait, some are landscape, but I've just grouped them together to avoid too much free space. I want to display two images per row (that's why I used two span6) - so yes, two columns. At the moment I am using this code (fiddle 3): ​​http://jsfiddle.net/3X3sY/ It centers the images, but now they is only 1 image per row.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - sorry. Got it now, it was just me being stupid.
One thing I can recommend to all people starting out with Twitter Bootstrap is: Know the difference between `row` and `row-fluid. ;-)